# Failed to deserialize variant EOSJS

Tags: development, javascript

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/eosasia/ping-eos
I am trying to connect my web application to my smart contract. when i use cleos to test the smart contract i am able to see that the smart contract is functioning as it should [image]

But when i try connecting to the application from the web app, i get this error.

[image]